# Put a UIViewController on top of a UINavigationController stack

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view controller that gets set from the first index of a uinavigationcontroller:

```
AViewController *aController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

But sometimes it doesn't work quite rigtht. When I do this below, after having an app open for a day it just stops at the navigation controller and doesn't load the AViewCo

Comment: That code doesn't do anything to "load" the AViewController. You're just assigning aController to whatever the navigation controller's root view controller is. Does the navigation controller already have an AViewController in its stack, or are you trying to add it there?

Comment: I have a bug where my navigation stack is empty. How do I add a view controller back into the stack?

Comment: You should figure out why your stack is empty and fix that bug. The stack should never be empty, since the root view controller should always be there. You must be deleting it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

you should check the navigationController when you use. Just combine the 
`setViewControllers:animated:` and `viewControllers objectAtIndex:0` methods. If there is not AViewController in the stack. Just new or assign the old one in it by `setViewControllers:animated:` .

Answer (score 0):

`self.navigationController.viewControllers` is just getting what you have currently in the **UINavigationController**. If you get nothing from it, it means that there are no **UIViewController** inside this **UINavigationController**. You probably do the check after getting it.

BTW, go check the documentation always. It might have other methods that help you with your situation. Not quite sure what you want to do.

And the time you access the **UIViewController** might not be loaded fully. That's why you can not get it.

Comment: why would it not be loaded fully?

Comment: You said that sometimes it does not work quite well. I don't know what that means.

Comment: sometimes as in right away when I go to the first view controller it works fine. But if I have my app open for 24 hours, the view controller at index 0 does not load

Comment: You probably go debug it. I really can't tell what your problem is by saying sometimes. Better you solve it yourself based on what you got here. Good luck.